# How to reset Swiper.js on click?

Tags: reset, init, swiper.js

**Hello everyone!**

I'm using Swiper.js for a project i'm working on and i'm facing something i can't fix. I've been googling and stackoverflowing and this is by far the best solution i found.

**What i'm trying to achieve:**

Let's say i have multiple swipers. And each has its own 'Reset' button. By clicking the 'Reset' button i want the swiper to go to its first slide and basically reset/refresh the whole swiper.

**The problem:**

Having a single swiper in the website does exactly what i want but once i add multiple swiper containers the 'Reset' button stops working.

**JSFiddle**
(Please add multiple swiper containers to see what i'm facing)

https://jsfiddle.net/alihoo/g3nfea5c/4/

**Thanks everyone!**

**HTML**

```
<div class="swiper-container">

  <button class="reset">reset</button>
  
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">01</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">02</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">03</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">04</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">05</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">06</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">07</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">08</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">09</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">10</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 364px;
}
.swiper-slide {
    line-height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #222;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  background: #007AFF;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  color: #007AFF;
}
```

**JS**

```
var settings = {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    spaceBetween: 32,
    initialSlide: 0,
    loop: true,
    loopAdditionalSlides: 1,
    freeMode: true,
    freeModeMinimumVelocity: 0.5,
    freeModeMomentumBounce: false,
    grabCursor: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'custom',
        renderCustom: function(swiper, current, total) {
            return ('0' + current).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + total).slice(-2);
        }
    }
};


var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', settings);


function resetSwiper() {
    var swiperWrapper = $('.swiper-wrapper');
    var newSlides = $('.swiper-wrapper').children('.swiper-slide').clone(true);
    mySwiper.destroy();
    swiperWrapper.empty().append(newSlides);
    $('.swiper-wrapper').attr('style', '');
    mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', settings);
}


$('.reset').click(function() {
    resetSwiper();
});
```